# Jenkins: How do I check out two repository URLs into the same workspace without deleting the first one?

Tags: eclipse, jenkins

our project structure has been split. On the one hand there is the /plugins folder containing all main plugin projects. On the other hand we have a /tests folder containing all the fragment projects that are the unit tests for their corresponding main plugin projects.

Jenkins lets me check out multiple repositories, and even to the same folder in the workspace.

The problem is that the first checkout is deleted when the second URL is checked out.

/plugins is placed into the workspace directory, then the workspace directory is "cleaned":

```
Cleaning local Directory .
```

Then the second directory /tests is checked out.

Of course I want that both folder contents are placed in the same workspace directory. How can I do that?

Comment: What tool(set) do you use for building?

Comment: Which repository(s) are you using?

Comment: @danowar - Is Toby's answer sufficient for your needs?  If so, please flag it as such.  If not, please update the question with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using Subversion to checkout your projects, you need to specify the "Local module directory" to something other than the default for each path you are checking out.

For example;

If you have svn://myrepo/myproject/plugins and svn://myrepo/myproject/tests, the configuration would be along the lines of;

```
Modules:
Repository URL : svn://myrepo/myproject/plugins
Local module directory (optional) : plugins

Repository URL : svn://myrepo/myproject/tests
Local module directory (optional) : tests
```

This would then inform Jenkins that it has two paths to checkout and into separate locations.

If you are trying to checkout a project into the subfolder of another working copy, you may have to use svn:externals on the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Jenkins 2.0 pipeline (previously named the Workflow Plugin), this is done differently for:

- The main repository
- Other additional repositories

Here I am specifically referring to the Multibranch Pipeline version 2.9.

**Main repository**

This is the repository that contains your `Jenkinsfile`.

In the *Configure* screen for your pipeline project, enter your repository name, etc.

Do not use *Additional Behaviors > Check out to a sub-directory*.  This will put your `Jenkinsfile` in the sub-directory [where Jenkins cannot find it](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40267).

In `Jenkinsfile`, check out the main repository in the subdirectory using `dir()`:

```
dir('subDir') {
    checkout scm
}
```

**Additional repositories**

If you want to check out more repositories, use the *Pipeline Syntax* generator to automatically generate a Groovy code snippet.

In the *Configure* screen for your pipeline project:

1. Select *Pipeline Syntax*. In the *Sample
   Step* drop down menu, choose *checkout: General SCM*.
2. Select your SCM system, such as *Git*.  Fill in the usual information
   about your repository or depot.
3. Note that in the Multibranch Pipeline, environment variable
   `env.BRANCH_NAME` contains the branch name of the main repository.
4. In the *Additional Behaviors* drop down menu, select
   *Check out to a sub-directory*
5. Click *Generate Groovy*. Jenkins will display the Groovy code snippet
   corresponding to the SCM checkout that you specified.
6. Copy this code into your pipeline script or `Jenkinsfile`.